# Nested loop not calculating correct amount due to previous value not being set beforehand

Tags: java, loops, recursion

I've come across a problem that has left me stumped. I basically have an array of Merchants, with each Merchant having an array that contains Payments.

Payments is a simple POJO with payment information, the loop is developed to retrieve each Payment from the Merchant, calculate the total amount for that day and store it in a new List. The code below is the code in question

```
private void calculateMerchantTotals()
{
    double dayAmount = 0;
    DayOfWeek previousDay = null;

    for( Merchant merchant : merchantList )
    {
        for( Payment payment : merchant.getPayments() )
        {
            if( payment.getPaymentDue().get(ChronoField.CLOCK_HOUR_OF_DAY) >= 16 && payment.getPaymentDue().get(ChronoField.CLOCK_HOUR_OF_DAY) != 24 )
            {
                payment.setPaymentDue( payment.getPaymentDue().plusDays(1) );
            }

            dayAmount += payment.getAmount();

            if( !payment.getPaymentDue().getDayOfWeek().equals( previousDay ) )
            {
                dayAmount = Math.round(dayAmount * 100.0) / 100.0;
                tableDataList.add( new TableData( payment.getPaymentDue().getDayOfWeek(), merchant.getMerchantName(), dayAmount ) );
                dayAmount = 0;
            }

            previousDay = payment.getPaymentDue().getDayOfWeek();
        }
    }

    System.out.println( tableDataList );
}
```

The variable `previousDay` is meant to store the current day and continue iterating over the current day amounting the totals. When a new day is discovered then the current amount should be added to the List, along with day, and Merchant name and should continue the loop again. Though this is not the case, as during the first iteration the `previousDay` variable is `null` and asserting `True` causing the first element to be inserted into the List, though obviously after the first element each next element is calculated and stored correctly.

The current output:

```
TableData: 
Day: MONDAY
Name: Sky
Amount: 64.4, 
TableData: 
Day: TUESDAY
Name: Sky
Amount: 185031.75, 
TableData: 
Day: WEDNESDAY
Name: Sky
Amount: 273188.4 ... (continued)
```

`TableData: Monday` should be `280105.19` but is only `64.4` as its inserting only the first element for Monday.

Any assistance that could highlight a new interpretation of the current implementation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you may add this condition to catch the first element just before your second condition (that checks for new days):

```
if(previousDay == null)
   previousDay = payment.getPaymentDue().getDayOfWeek();
```

When you add to the list, use the `previousDay`, not the current one as the total values collected are for the previous days. You need the previous Merchant names as well.
This should work, hopefully. Here is your code after my additions:

```
private void calculateMerchantTotals()
{
    double dayAmount = 0;
    DayOfWeek previousDay = null;
    String previousName = "";

    for( Merchant merchant : merchantList )
    {
        for( Payment payment : merchant.getPayments() )
        {
            if( payment.getPaymentDue().get(ChronoField.CLOCK_HOUR_OF_DAY) >= 16 && payment.getPaymentDue().get(ChronoField.CLOCK_HOUR_OF_DAY) != 24 )
            {
                payment.setPaymentDue( payment.getPaymentDue().plusDays(1) );
            }

            dayAmount += payment.getAmount();

            // The newly injected condition here
            if(previousDay == null)
               previousDay = payment.getPaymentDue().getDayOfWeek();

            if( !payment.getPaymentDue().getDayOfWeek().equals( previousDay ) )
            {
                dayAmount = Math.round(dayAmount * 100.0) / 100.0;
                tableDataList.add( new TableData( previousDay, previousName, dayAmount ) );
                dayAmount = 0;
            }

            previousDay = payment.getPaymentDue().getDayOfWeek();
            previousName = merchant.getMerchantName();
        }
    }
    // For adding the last day into the list
    tableDataList.add( new TableData( previousDay, previousName, dayAmount ) );

    System.out.println( tableDataList );
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Its not that I want to exclude it, but I want to include every element not just the first.

Comment: So, you need it to enter the `if` condition when there is a new day, right?

Comment: Yes, but during the first iteration `previousDay` is `null` causing the `if` to assert `True`. therefore, inserting the first iteration and then continues to set `previousDay` to `Monday` and proceeds to not add any other values for `Monday`.

Comment: I see. I got your point. I revised my answer. I hope you get it working now. Thanks.

Comment: I like your thought process there but unfortunately it doesn't work, as the following `if` still asserts `false`

Comment: That's right. The following `if` should be `false` to keep collecting its `dayAmount`. Once the next day comes, it will be `true` and the total amount will be added to the list. I wonder why it doesn't work; looks like I still didn't understand your objective well. Could you please check the results you got and let me know what are they?

Comment: With your add condition `Monday` is not even being output, though the rest are as expected

Comment: I just realized your problem. You should add to the list the value of previousDay, not the current. Please have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Apologies, I left in some unless code in another function, after removing it and updating with your snippets it worked! Good job TeeKea you've done it!

Comment: Oh, really. Glad to hear that! Wish you the best, @Tom C.